# For an Authorize.net configuration, will a comma delimited transaction response work?

Tags: civicontribute, configuration, authorize.net

We need to change our Authorize.net Direct Response settings to integrate with another system and I wanted to know if I set my Delimited Response to YES and make the Default Field Separator ,(comma) will Civi still be able to read the transaction response?

Thanks!